# Create PDF with mpdf and chart.js

Tags: php, chart.js, mpdf

I want to create a PDF report using mpdf. The report include a lot of pages  which I created with html and css, this works great and it looks good. My problem is that I want to include some charts on a couple of pages and I don't know how to accomplish this. How do I insert charts created from chart.js?

I have searched the stackoverflow and web all day but I haven't found a good answer. I have found some threads where you create where you create images from canvas using toBase64Image and then save file to server. I got this to work but then I'm stuck again because I need to generate the chart images before I create the PDF. I tried to generate the images on a "start page" and when the charts is completed I move to the pdf page. But this was very slow and not very nice because you see the chart before you move to the pdf page.

Is this possible or do I have to start over with something else? I that case where and what?

Comment: You can use wkhtmltopdf for this convert. this soft ware has an option for waiting load js. But if your server is not ubuntu be careful, you should install correct font. You should generate your html file then convert this file to pdf in php.

Answer (score 0):

check out the pchart library https://packagist.org/packages/szymach/c-pchart
[Pchart](https://packagist.org/packages/szymach/c-pchart)

you can generate charts as images and boom.. add it to the image tag.